# mvc2 html.textbox from model, dynamically update as marker dragged before saving

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, textbox

I am trying to populate `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FaveRunLatLng1)%>` dynamically as a user drags a marker around a map.

I need to use this value as the map is initialized with the `FaveRunLatLng1` value. However, when the user drags the marker, this needs to be updated so that when the `Save` button is hit, the most current `LatLng` is saved. The code for the marker is in Javascript, Google maps API v3.

Should I be using something like:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FaveRunLatLng1, new {@class = "coords"})%> 
</div>
```

This is the google maps listener for the drag event:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
            var point = marker.getPosition(); 
            var lat = point.lat();
            var lng = point.lng();

            coordStr = lat.toString() + ", " + lng.toString();

            document.getElementById("newCoords").value = coordStr;
            map.setCenter(point);
        });
```

the variable `newCoords` acts as a test to ensure the dragged marker is updating as it is dragged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should do it that way. But instead of using test `newCoords`, just use the element ID that got created by the `HtmlHelper` which is `FaveRunLatLng1`:

```
document.getElementById("FaveRunLatLng1").value = coordStr;
```

This means you'd be accessing your textbox by ID rather than CSS class. I suppose you've provided class name `coords` for the purpose of accessing your textbox?